# How do I write a WSDL file to accept arbitrary SOAP Headers?

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have a client that wants to send a large number of SOAP Header fields to my web service. The only thing I am expected to do with these values is reflect them back.

What is the proper way to handle this? They would like me to define each of them in the WSDL, but they are quite specific and will have no meaning to any other clients.

I have some code that simply intercepts the request and copies the headers back onto the response, but I don't know how to handle this in the WSDL. Is it legitimate to simply leave them out yet? Or a generic way to say "send me anything and I'll send it back"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in [WSDL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap:header), it isn't required to list all the headers in the WSDL file:

> It is not necessary to exhaustively list all headers that appear in the SOAP Envelope using soap:header. For example, extensions (see section 2.1.3) to WSDL may imply specific headers should be added to the actual payload and it is not required to list those headers here.

I can't find the corresponding section in the WSDL 2.0 spec, but I don't think this would have changed.